# SubSonic Return ExecuteSingle for Stored Procedure

Tags: stored-procedures, subsonic

I wish to return a single ScPollOption item using a Stored Procedure via the code below:

```
public ScPollOption FetchPollOptionByID(int optionID)
    {
        StoredProcedure sp = SPs.ScPollOptionGetOptionByID(optionID);
        return sp;
    }
```

When working with a query I would use:

```
ExecuteSingle<ScPollOption>()
```

but SubSonic only allows for sp.ExecuteTypedList<> and sp.ExecuteScalar<>.

How can I return a single ScPollOption item?

Thanks

Dan

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know it's not terribly attractive, but this would work if you're able to use the LINQ extensions:

```
sp.ExecuteTypedList<ScPollOption>().FirstOrDefault();
```

You could also execute an `IDataReader` and inflate the `ScPollOption` object manually:

```
ScPollOption item;

using (IDataReader reader = sp.ExecuteReader())
{
    if (reader.Read())
    {
        item = new ScPollOption();
        item.SomeProperty = reader.GetValue(0);
        // Set additional properties
    }
}

return item;
```